# IsAliased always null in GetSchemaTable

Tags: c#, sql-server, getschematable

GetSchemaTable() always returns IsAliased as null, and BaseColumnName is always the same as ColumnName, even though I have used an alias name to fetch column data from Stored Procedure.

SP:

```sql
SELECT u.Name AS [Display Name]  
  ,code AS [Display Code]
........
```

C#:

```cs
DbDataReader reader = null;
DataTable dt = reader.GetSchemaTable();
```

Comment: If you're using a Stored Procedure, then whatever is calling that Procedure will have no idea what underlying objects, and their aliases, are used within that Procedure.

Comment: Get Schema is not looking at the stored procedure.  Get Schema is just looking at the databases, tables, and columns in the server.

Comment: Update- was able to solve the issue by adding commandBehavior.

Answer (score 0):

Was able to solve the issue by adding commandBehavior